# Laravel heroku js not working after second push commit

Tags: javascript, laravel, heroku

I am try to deploy my Laravel project to Heroku.

When i am pushing the code the first time, all functionality, css and js are working fine and the style is the same as the local environment.

After I push the second time any modification on html dropdown menu and the js functionality is not working on Heroku, but it is still working on local environment. I think the js assets needs to be precompiled OR something else.

Answer (score 0):

Probably It needs to compile again If you don't have a script ready to do It automatic. You can access your application on Heroku , and select the more option , right aside of your project's name , therefore select the Run Console option , and finally running your compile command , like: "npm run production".

To do It automatic you can always set a command inside composer.json , at the scripts object. something like:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall":[
        "npm run prod"
    ]
}
```

Comment: still the same dropdown not working at heroku and route to href # and heroku conosle give me this when try to run npm run production cannot find command

Comment: I see... , try to find the right command at the package.json file. It must be listed on the scripts object.